# Exception: Duplicate files copied in APK com/worklight

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

When try to build project after I include Worklight Library I received bellow error

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK com/worklight/wlclient/messages_it.properties
>       File1: C:\Users\user1\AndroidStudioProjects\DIMP_APP\DIMP_APP\app\libs\worklight-android.jar
>       File2: C:\Users\user1\AndroidStudioProjects\DIMP_APP\DIMP_APP\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.ibm.mobile.foundation\ibmmobilefirstplatformfoundation\7.1.0.0\jars\classes.jar

Comment: Please provide **clear** reproduction steps.

Answer (score 0):

As you did not supply the steps you've followed to add the library to your project, I suggest to verify that you have followed the latest official steps to do so, from here: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/hello-world/configuring-a-native-android-application-with-the-mfp-sdk/

Essentially:

1. Create a new native project in MobileFirst Studio in order to have the latest SDK generated
2. Copy the worklight-android.jar, uicandroid.jar, bcprov.jar, and android-async-http.jar files from the generated NativeAPI folder to the new native Android application, in the /libs directory.
3. [Android Studio only] Right-click any of the added .jar files and select Add as library to add all libraries.
4. [Android Studio only] Create an assets folder under src\main
5. Copy the wlclient.properties file from the previously created MobileFirst native API folder to the new native Android application, in the /assets directory.
6. Add the following permissions to the AndroidManifest.xml file

   ```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
   ```
7. Add the MobileFirst UI activity:

   ```
   <activity android:name="com.worklight.wlclient.ui.UIActivity" />
   ```